# Invalid use of member function C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm trying to build a STL container named `SetList` as shown below

```
template
    <typename T>
class SetList
{
public:
    struct ListNode
    {
        T info;
        ListNode * next;

        ListNode(T newInfo, ListNode * newNext)
            : info(newInfo), next(newNext)
        {
        }

        static ListNode * insert(const char *s)
        {
            *head->info = "test"; //error occurs here, whenever i try to assign head: "invalid use of member ‘SetList<T>::head’ in static member function"
        }
    };

    struct iterator
    {
        typedef std::forward_iterator_tag iterator_category;
        typedef iterator self_type;
        typedef T value_type;
        typedef T& reference;
        typedef ListNode * pointer;
        typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
    private:
        pointer buf;
    public:
        iterator(pointer ptr)
            :buf(ptr)
        {   
        }
    };

    SetList() : head(new ListNode("", NULL)) {}
    iterator first(){return iterator(head);}
    iterator last(){return iterator(NULL);}
    ~SetList(){}

private:
    ListNode * head;
};
```

As I understand it, the issue has to do with the fact that I'm using a static, and as a result `this` doesn't exist in the scope of the function, but from my understanding, I have remedied this using `ListNode *head` in the private area - or is that incorrect?

I'm trying to build a simple insert function for the linked list but cannot access the head without error.

Comment: which `head` do you want to set in that function? The `head` as declared in the class is not static, thus there is no `head` if there is no object of that class

Comment: @tobi303 I am trying to set `head` that is defined in the private area of `SetList`i.e. `ListNode * head`, or do I have to declare this as `static ListNode *head` to make it accessible?

Comment: _" I have remedied this using `ListNode *head` in the private area - or is that incorrect?"_ Did that compile? In this case `head` must be a static member variable. Why do you think the `insert()` function should be `statiic`?

Comment: The `head` is not static and hence cannot be accessed from a `static` function. You either need to make the `head` static as well or make the `insert` method non-static

Comment: It seems like you have some problems of understanding what `static` does. A static member does not belong to any object, but to the class as a whole. Static functions are called without an object of that class and thus it cannot access any objects members (but only static members).

Comment: "STL" does not mean "anything that uses templates".

Comment: @molbdnilo, what makes you think it's not going to be included in the STL ? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `head` is not `static`, every `ListNode` has it's own `head`. Therefore you need the `this` pointer to access the `head`.
You could make `head` `static`, but that would essentially mean all lists have the same head and you effectively can have only one list.

The better solution would be to make `insert` not `static`, which would allow you to access `head` and make logical sense, because you need to say which list to insert into.

Answer (score 0):

Your insert function should not be `static` nor part of your node. It should be a member of your SetList. If you'd like it to be part of your node as well then you should create a method in your node that also accepts a `SetList&` parameter and then calls the insert on the list.

Also you are now assuming that T is always assignable from a string which may defy the point of using a template.

Answer (score 0):

`static` functions or fields within a class/struct are shared by all instances of that class/struct. Since you don't need an object of that class to use a `static` function this has the logical consequence that `static` functions can NOT access instance fields.

In your example `ListNode * head` is an instance field that belongs to an object, and each object has its own `head` so there's no way to know to which `head` you are refering to when you use it in a `static` method since those are object independent (you do not have access to the `this` pointer inside those methods).

For methods within a class to have access to the `this` pointer (to be able to access instance fields) they need to NOT be declared `static`.